# Neat representation of results in Julia after a loop

Tags: julia

I have created a small code in Julia that is able to use `function iteration` to solve a simple non-linear problem.

The code is the following:

```
"""
Problem: find the root of f(x) = exp(-x) - x
using the fixed point iteration
(aka function iteration)

Solution: f(x) = exp(-x) - x = 0
          x = exp(-x)

"""

i = 0;              # initialize first iteration
x = 0;              # initialize solution
error = 1;          # initialize error bound
xvals = x;          # initialize array of iterates

tic()

while error >= 1e-10
        y = exp(-x);
        xvals = [xvals;y];      # It is not needed actually
        error = abs(y-x);
        x = y;
        i = i + 1;
        println(["Solution", x', "Error:", error', "Iteration no:", i'])
end

toc()
```

In the above code the results are not neat for there are many decimal numbers. To my understanding, using `println` may not be a good idea and instead `@printf` or `sprintf` must be used, however, I was not able to put everything in one line.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but for what it is worth there is a function `compute_fixed_point` in the `QuantEcon` library that would apply the function iteration for you. So, conditional on having called `Pkg.add("QuantEcon")` and `using QuantEcon`, you could solve this problem via `sol = compute_fixed_point(x->exp(-x), guess)`, where `guess` is the starting guess.

Comment: You sir made my day. It been some time since I visited their site (Quant-Econ) and now they have included Julia examples also. Pefect, just perfect.

Comment: Awesome, glad you are excited about it! We have spent some time making sure the same code is available in both the python and julia versions of QuantEcon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for `printf` is (roughly) the same for all languages,
but it is indeed arcane.

You can use `%f` for floats, `%e` for floats in scientific notation,
`%d` for integers, `%s` for strings. 
The numbers between the `%` and the letter are
the number of digits (or characters) before and after the comma.

```
i = 0
x = 0
error = Inf
while error >= 1e-10
    x, previous = exp(-x), x
    error = abs( x - previous )
    i += 1
    @printf( 
      "Value: %1.3f  Error: %1.3e  Iteration: %3d\n", 
      x, error, i 
    )
end
```

You could also have tried `round` or `signif`, 
but since round decimal numbers cannot always be represented exactly as floats,
that does not work reliably.